# Programatically load data finto uitableview using predicate coredata as if table has already had row selected

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, predicate, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm trying to use the excellent code in http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-core-data-uitableview-drill-down/ to populate fur pop-overs

```
// Override point for customization after app launch    
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

// We're not using undo. By setting it to nil we reduce the memory footprint of the app
[context setUndoManager:nil];

if (!context) {
    NSLog(@"Error initializing object model context");
    exit(-1);
}

// Get the url of the local xml document
NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"xml"]];

NSError *parseError = nil;

// Parse the xml and store the results in our object model
LocationsParser *xmlParse = [[LocationsParser alloc] initWithContext:context];
[xmlParse parseXMLFileAtURL:xmlURL parseError:&parseError];
[xmlParse release];


// Create a table view controller
RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];



/*
 ORIGINAL
 */
rootViewController.managedObjectContext = context;
rootViewController.entityName = @"County";
```

If I change the entityName to

```
rootViewController.entityName = @"Province";
```

It loads the second tier of data into the initial view, but want I want is the load only the second tier of data that belongs to a particular first tier row.

So replacing the two lines I've marked as original with

```
// Get the object the user selected from the array
NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [entityArray objectAtIndex:0];

// Pass the managed object context
rootViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

rootViewController.entityName = @"Province";

// Create a query predicate to find all child objects of the selected object. 
NSPredicate *predicate = nil;
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ProvinceToCounty == %@)", selectedObject];
NSLog(@"selectedObject %@",selectedObject);
```

It would work if I could work out how the replace entityArray with a reference to the initial loading the data.

Hope that makes sense.

Without any code what I'm hoping to achieve is to use the XML to populate four different pop-over uitableviews, each one has already drilled down a level into the data as it loads. I can get straight to all the second data from all the first tier rows, but that's no good, I only want the second tier data from one first tier row per popoverview.

ie emulate this happening

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Force the data from index 1 of first tier
    NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [entityArray objectAtIndex:1];

    rootViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    NSPredicate *predicate = nil;


    rootViewController.entityName = @"Province";

    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ProvinceToCounty == %@)", selectedObject];

    NSLog(@"selectedObject %d %@",indexPath.row, selectedObject);
```

I've learnt a lot in the last four hours but not enough and now I'm defeated...